# How to dynamically display an image in vue

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

We have a list of products, each with their own ID and their own image.

```
getImgUrl(id) {
      return require(`../../../../../img/products/accessory-${id}.png`);
    },
```

The images live inside the wp-uploads folder of the wordpress site that I mount the vue app inside of. Normally we can just use absolute paths for image sources, but I need to have this image source be available at runtime not just during compile, which works using the `require` in the return statement, but it is only working on my local dev server and not in the production build.

I don't know too much about webpack, but I am trying to learn more. Any points in the right direction would be lovely. Thank you!

Comment: The `require` approach you're using would work with Webpack only if all the possible images existed at the relative path at compile time. It would also bundle every `accessory-*.png` image in that `products` directory into the app. Is that what you are going for?

Comment: @kdau Yes, all of the images used in the vue app are in the wp-uploads/img/products so I could use that as a public path? I've been reading the webpack docs trying to get more familiar